# How dragDrop works in Highmaps with mappoint (Highcharts)

Tags: highcharts

I tried adding following `dragDrop` property in series. But points on the maps are not getting dragged.

```
 series:[
     {
        type: 'mappoint',
        dragDrop: {
            draggableX: true,
            draggableY: true
        }
 ]
```

I am using Highmap of mappoint type with lat and long.
Example: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/mappoint-latlon/)

Versions `highcharts-react-official@2.0.0` and `highcharts@7.0.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load `modules/draggable-points.js`.

**API:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mappoint.dragDrop

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0cq3a9h4/1/

Comment: awesome, it worked. In react I included following: 

import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import Draggble from 'highcharts/modules/draggable-points.src';

and initialized as 

Draggble(Highcharts)

Comment: Doesn't work now - try the jsfiddle. I'm trying to find why our app stopped working after a HC upgrade... they changed / broke something